# The function $f(x)= 4-3\sin(x)$ is defined for the domain $0\leq x\leq 2\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Solve the equation $f(x) = 2$.
I reached the stage $\sin(x) = {2\over 3}$ but then (as I remember it was solved) using $x = \sin^{-1}(2/3)$ (sine inverse) I get the answer $x = 41.81$ but the correct answer is $x = 0.730$ or $2.41$. Why is this so? Sorry it might be a silly question but it had been long since I studied mathematics so I kinda forgot everything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You  have to convert the degrees into radians. Once you do that I think you get the right answer.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks you're right that worked but whats the difference between Degrees and Radians?

Comment: One is a multiple of the other, so  $1$ radian is $\frac{180}{\pi}$ degrees. Both are important, degrees because it expresses many (commonly occuring) angles in natural numbers which are easy to add / subtract  etc, and radians because of Taylor expansion and other analytic formulas of the sine working well with the radian measure. You can use the one you are comfortable with, but I would prefer if you were familiar with radians.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We are given the function $f(x) = 4 - 3\sin x$ defined on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.  Notice that $x$ is measured in radians.

Solving the equation $f(x) = 2$ yields
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 2\\
4 - 3\sin x & = 2\\
-3\sin x & = -2\\
\sin x & = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}
Thus, we must find all angles in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ such that $\sin x = \dfrac{2}{3}$.

A particular solution is 
$$x = \arcsin\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \approx 0.729727656227$$
Since the sine of angle in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis) is the $y$-coordinate of a point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle, we must find all angles in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ such that the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle at a point with $y$-coordinate $2/3$. There are two such angles, one in the first quadrant, which we have found, and one in the second quadrant.

[image: symmery_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

By symmetry, $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin x$.  Hence, the other solution in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is 
$$x = \pi - \arcsin\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \approx 2.41186499736$$

Answer (score -3):

The correct answer is:$$x=\arcsin(2/3)=0.7297276563$$

Comment: ...and $\pi -\arcsin\frac23$